# Espresso test the camera intent when imageuri is passed as extra

Tags: android, android-intent, android-espresso

I need to stub the camera intent by creating a image file at the path provided in the intent extra.
Espresso can only respond with activityresult. Where can i perform the operation to create the file at passed path from intent extra.

**Code for launching camera**

`File destination = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "app_name" + System.currentTimeMillis() + ".jpg");`

imageUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(getApplicationContext(), getApplicationContext().getPackageName() + ".fileprovider", destination);
        Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, imageUri);

startActivityForResult(intent, AppConstants.REQUEST_CODE_CAMERA);

**Code for stubbing intent in test**

`Instrumentation.ActivityResult result = new Instrumentation.ActivityResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, null);
        intending(hasAction(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE)).respondWith(result);`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to create a IntentCallback to intercept the `Uri` value and save a sample image there.

Sample in Kotlin

```
  intentCallback = IntentCallback {
        if (it.action == "android.media.action.IMAGE_CAPTURE") {
            it.extras.getParcelable<Uri>("output").run {
                val inStream = Resources.getResource(sampleImageFileName).openStream()
                val outStream = activity.contentResolver.openOutputStream(this)
                ByteStreams.copy(inStream, outStream)
            }
        }
    }
```

You need to register your callback before the intent trigger event

```
  IntentMonitorRegistry.getInstance().addIntentCallback(intentCallback)
```

And don't to forget to unregister at end

```
  IntentMonitorRegistry.getInstance().removeIntentCallback(intentCallback)
```

Answer (score 12):

Ismael answer is perfect. For those looking for solution in java, Here it is.

```
intending(hasAction(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE)).respondWith(
            new Instrumentation.ActivityResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, null));

IntentCallback intentCallback = new IntentCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onIntentSent(Intent intent) {
            if (intent.getAction().equals("android.media.action.IMAGE_CAPTURE")) {
                try {
                    Uri imageUri = intent.getParcelableExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT);
                    Context context = InstrumentationRegistry.getTargetContext();
                    Bitmap icon = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(
                            context.getResources(),
                            R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
                    OutputStream out = getTargetContext().getContentResolver().openOutputStream(imageUri);
                    icon.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, out);
                    out.flush();
                    out.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    GenericUtility.handleException(e);
                }
            }
        }
    };
    IntentMonitorRegistry.getInstance().addIntentCallback(intentCallback);

 //Perform action here
 onView(withId(R.id.tv_take_photo)).perform(click());
```

Answer (score 1):

Ismael and Gupta's answers are correct. For those who want a complete example, I made a complete solution based on their example in Kotlin. The code below takes photo for multiple `imageView` and also verifies if the correct image is loaded in the respective `imageview` by checking the `imageView.tag` property. From the development code, the image name has to be set in the `imageView.setTag(imageName)`

```
private var imageName = "No Image Name"

@Test
fun verifyPhotoTaken() {
    intending(hasAction(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE)).respondWith(
            ActivityResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, null))

    takePhoto(R.id.imageview1, R.drawable.ic_launcher)
    takePhoto(R.id.imageview2, R.drawable.some_image)
}

private fun takePhoto(imageViewId : Int, resourceId : Int) {
    val cameraIntentCallback = intentCallback(resourceId)
    IntentMonitorRegistry.getInstance().addIntentCallback(cameraIntentCallback)
    onView(withId(imageViewId)).perform(click())
    onView(withId(imageViewId)).check(matches(hasDrawable(imageName)))
    IntentMonitorRegistry.getInstance().removeIntentCallback(cameraIntentCallback)
}

private fun intentCallback(resourceId : Int = R.drawable.ic_launcher) :IntentCallback  {
    return IntentCallback {
        if (it.action == MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE) {
            it.extras?.getParcelable<Uri>(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT).run {
                imageName = File(it.getParcelableExtra<Parcelable>(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT).toString()).name
                val context : Context = InstrumentationRegistry.getInstrumentation().targetContext
                val outStream = context.contentResolver.openOutputStream(this)
                val bitmap : Bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.resources, resourceId)
                bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, outStream)
            }
        }
    }
}

fun hasDrawable(drawableResource: String) : BoundedMatcher<View, ImageView> {
    return object : BoundedMatcher<View, ImageView> (ImageView::class.java) {
        override fun describeTo(description: Description?) {
            description?.appendText("has drawable")
        }

        override fun matchesSafely(item: ImageView?): Boolean {
            return item?.drawable != null && item.tag.toString().contains(drawableResource)
        }

    }
}
```